# Why does Cloudberry Backup not list files correctly when using Amazon Glaicer?

Tags: backup, cloud-storage, amazon-glacier

About 10 days ago, I began a trial of Cloudberry Backup (CBB).  Their Explorer product is very good and I am looking to save a few bucks by using Amazon Glacier as my offsite backup at home instead of CrashPlan.  The first backup set, with my external hard drive as a destination, worked without incident. CBB copied the files and I can browse them just fine.

Such was not the case with Amazon Glacier.  It did not have trouble connecting with my AWS Account.  I use an IAM user which only has access to Glacier instead of the admin account.  After connecting my account, I created a backup plan to use "archive mode" (to save costs by uploading fewer files at a time) and copy a number of files and folders to Glacier then monitor them in real time for changes.

However the backup took several days to complete.  When it did, I could not browse to individual files using the "Backup Storage" tab's file explorer view.  According to the AWS web interface the data was in Glacier. A third plan created using "regular" mode ran without incident after which the problem above seemed to correct itself.  Than I ran a consistency check last night and found the error "File was not found in local repository".  Everything disappeared from the file explorer, but reappeared this morning.

My understanding is Amazon Glacier puts data in a deep freeze and limits how it can be accessed.  In particular I've read one cannot easily retrieve a few files unlike with CrashPlan. However CBB's behavior is inconsistent and confusing.  Sometimes I can see individual files, sometimes I can't. Customer Support was not terribly helpful.  Does anyone have any experience with the program they can share?  Does Cloudberry Backup keep track of individual files uploaded to Amazon Glacier?  My goal is to have an experience as similar as possible to CrashPlan with lower cost and easier access to files if I end my subscription.

Answer (score 1):

This is Andy from CloudBerry Lab. Thank you for posting the issue on SuperUser! We have identified the issue with Consistency Check + Archive Mode where the consistency check clears up our internal local repository - it causes no data on the Backup Storage view after it completes. No cloud data is affected. You can get data back after refreshing the Backup Storage and then choose "Retrieve Archive Content" option under Archives | BackupPlanName. We will update the thread as soon as the issue if fixed.

Regards
Andy

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I suspected there was an issue with the local repository since everything uploads just fine.  When something is uploaded in archive mode, is one supposed to be able to view the contents of the archives in Cloudberry Backup?  Or are files uploaded in that way more or less akin to stuff in a box (i.e. not easily retrievable except by getting the whole archive).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. [CloudBerry Backup](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup) uses a local repository to keep a list of files that were backed up. If there are any changes to Glacier outside CloudBerry Backup, it requires to resync the repository (that will initiate an inventory job if there is no current one) to update the local repository. If there are any inconsistency after the repository sync, we have to diagnose the issue. For further diagnosing, please send your diagnostic logs and provide some more details of the issue - you can sent them directly from the product by going to Tools | Diagnostic Log and use Send button there. The logs will be sent automatically to our support system; a ticket will be created for you and you will get an email notification.